# What does そうだった means

Tags: meaning

I read that そう means it is/it so and that adding the だった, means past tense so it would only make sense that そうだった would translate into it was.

I heard someone in an anime say this and the translation was `you are right`.
I can understand how `it is so` can mean you are right/ you are correct, but shouldn't it be you were correct ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What came just before that そうだった  ? ______ My guess:  [A] says an explanation. and [B] says そうだった -- meaning.  [ I see.  that makes sense now. ] (what i had in mind previously was not what you just told me) ----  The past tense is used because the sentiment is -- I now see that it was so (that's how it was) all along.  or So i realize now.

Answer (score 2):

そうだった -- often means

- ( I had forgotten that )　　 [ it was so ].  　　  or
- ( I should have remembered / realized / guessed .... that )　　 [ it was so ].

> http://shouyouki.web.fc2.com/ta.htm
>
> なお、「だった」「かった」は、回想のほかに、「想定外の現在の状態」を示すこともある。
>
> 「お前はそんな奴だったのか」とか、「こんなことも知らなかったのか」というときの「た」は、今も続く状態を今知ったということを示しており、古文の「気づきの『けり』」と同じような機能を果たしている。

Answer (score 2):

Just to add onto the above answer:

そうだった is a very common expression and can have different meaning depending on context and inflection.
English equivalents would be:

"Oh...yeah, that's right."

"Really?" -With an inflection at the end.  Meaning I'm not sure if I believe you or that's kind of strange.